# Image to SVG file for loading it on Android

Tags: android, svg, svg-android

Is it possible to convert an image to svg file and load it on android using [svg-android](https://code.google.com/p/svg-android/) lib.?

I tried with Inkscape and it is not loading on my app. But if i try with this [image](http://code.google.com/p/svg-android/downloads/detail?name=android.svg), it works!

Please guide me in this regard.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no prior research nor minimal understanding of the problem being solved

Answer (score 0):

svg-android has some limitations.  There are a number of features of SVG that it doesn't support.  You may well have more luck with another library.  For example, try my one: [AndroidSVG](http://code.google.com/p/androidsvg/)